# Change "blurriness" of image as you scroll by it.

Tags: jquery, html

I currently have a banner image which starts off blurred and then as you scroll down it unblurs, which works great. **[You can view the example here](http://hutchcreative.co.uk/v2/index.html)**

However once it gets to around 900px I would like it to start to blur again. And I'm not sure of the best way to do this?

**Below is my HTML:**

```
<div id="blurred-image-container">
    <div class="img-src" style="background-image:url('images/mainImage_blur.png')"></div>
    <div class="img-src clean-image" style="background-image:url('images/mainImage.png');opacity:0"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
            d = $(document).height(),
            c = $(window).height(),
            opacityVal = (s / 600);

        $('.clean-image').css('opacity', opacityVal);
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add to scroll function `if($(this).scrollTop() > 900) { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is purely a math problem.**

And the easiest, and probably most efficient way to solve this is using a Sinus curve.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
            d = $(document).height(),
            c = $(window).height(),
            $clImg = $('.clean-image');

        var clImgTop = $clImg.offset().top;
        var clImgBtm = $clImg.height() + cleanImageTop;

        var opacityVal = getOpacityBy(clImgTop-100, clImgBtm+100, s+c/2, 0);

        $clImg.css('opacity', opacityVal);
    });
});

function getOpacityBy(start, end, current, opacityIfOutside){
    if(start > current || end < current)
        return opacityIfOutside;

    // Ratio is calculated to translate the pixels, 
    // to a value between 0 and 180 degrees
    var ratio = (end-start) / 180,
        currentRelativePos = current-start;

    // The sine function expects its input as radians
    return Math.sin(toRadians(currentRelativePos / ratio));
}

function toRadians (angle) {
  return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
}
```

Here is the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YbSPq/7/)** for it
**OBS: NOTE that the original poster has changed image locations, which is why the fiddle doesn't work now.**

---

**Make sense of it all**
All you are really doing is controlling the `Length`, `Start` and `End` point of the Sinus Curve
[image: Sinus Curve for blurring]